# How to pass a dynamically typed Action<T> to a method

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, delegates

I have a 3d party job execution library (hangfire) that accepts `Action<T>`:

```
Add(Action<T> action);
```

I can easily call something like that:

```
Add((MyJob job) => job.Run());
```

But I want to load the job dynamically via reflection, so I have a class name "MyNamespace.MyJob" that I can use. I cannot figure out how I can create required parameter with reflection.

P.S. The class implements IJob, but I cannot unfortunately use `Action<IJob>`, because hangfire will use that  argument to resolve from the DI container later.

Comment: How does Hangfire supply that parameter?

Comment: Not sure if you mean this: RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(Action<T> action)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Hangfire uses the type argument to ask the DI container to supply a value. That's why the delegate actually needs to have the right type. Using `Action<object>` would not work.

```
static void AddToHangfire<T>() where T : ICommand {
 Add((T job) => job.Run());
}
```

Now you need to use reflection to call that method. You can use `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod` and `MethodInfo.Invoke` to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did work right away. I used typeof().GetMethod().MakeGenericMethod().Invoke(). I was trying to create an Action<T> which was very hard, but this workaround with the method that has Action<T> inside is brilliant :)

Comment: Yeah, it's a common reflection trick. You only have to do the nasty stuff once.

Comment: can you add the part to answer of usage?